# how to call a url asynchronously from a celery task

Tags: python, asynchronous, celery, nonblocking

I'm using celery with Tornado and I was wondering how can I call a url asynchronously inside a task.

I'm looking for something in the lines of:

```
@celery.task
def my_task(data):
    def handle_response(response):
        if response.error:
            print "error"
        else:
            print "success"

    http_client = httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
    http_client.fetch('some url', handle_response, method='POST', body=data)
```

or:

```
@celery.task
@gen.coroutine
def my_task(data):
    http_client = httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
    response = yield http_client.fetch('some url', method='POST', body=data)
    raise gen.Result(response.body)
```

My problem now is that I don't get to the response handler.
Using HttpClient instead works but since it blocks the server, I'm looking for a non-blocking solution.

BTW, My broker is redis and I wish to keep it (tornado-celery callbacks work only with pika if it provides a solution)

Comment: Hi, In my opinion your approach is an overhead. Celery is already made to execute jobs asynchronously so what better place that a celery task to do a blocking URL call ? Adding an async url call in async task is a kind of overhead. Maybe you can explain your use-case, this could help in finding a proper solution.

Comment: @MauroRocco I guess you are right. Since my tasks script is part of my application and even uses tornado's http client, I was working under the impression that it's the same context but we're not Kansas anymore , are we? :)

Comment: I'm Italian, and to get the meaning of the expression "we're not Kansas anymore" I had to check on urban dictionary. Now I'm able to answer you: No, Dorothy we are not! WOF WOF! :-D

Comment: @MauroRocco Ben fatto! :) Do you want to answer my question so I could accept your answer?

Comment: Done! Thanks and congrats for your italian :-)

Comment: courtesy of Google translate :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion your approach is an overhead. Celery is already made to execute jobs asynchronously so what better place that a celery task to do a blocking URL call ? Adding an async url call in async task is a kind of overhead. I hope this helps.